# Can't get basic stats about a column

Tags: r

I am running some basic code. I have cleaned up the data and want to explore some attributes. I run the describe(census$Age) code but I get the following error 
    Error in x - mx : non-numeric argument to binary operator.

What does this mean and how do i fix it please?

This is for a project I am working on.

```
Error in x - mx : non-numeric argument to binary operator
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In mean.default(x, na.rm = na.rm) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
2: In var(if (is.vector(x) || is.factor(x)) x else as.double(x), na.rm = 
na.rm) :
  NAs introduced by coercion
3: In mean.default(sort(x, partial = half + 0L:1L)[half + 0L:1L]) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
4: In mean.default(x, na.rm = na.rm, trim = trim) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
5: In var(if (is.vector(x) || is.factor(x)) x else as.double(x), na.rm = 
na.rm) :
  NAs introduced by coercion
6: In mean.default(x) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

I just want to be able to get stat data from this column. stuff like min, max, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the column to as.numeric and then installed the packaged pastecs.

```
 install.packages("pastecs")
 library(pastecs)
 census1$Age<-as.numeric(census1$Age)
 stat.desc(census1$Age)
 can also use summary(census1$Age) but that does not give you standard deviation
```

Thank you.

Comment: Is this meant to be an answer to your question (which is totally valid to do)? If not, please edit your question and delete this one here.